# Swift Popover open SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, popover, pushviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm new in the development environment Swift, I have a problem where I can not get rid of it, I created a popover, inside I have a "UITableViewController", in which each cell must open a "UIViewController" in the side menu "SWRevealViewController" the problem is: the popover opens the desired page correctly "Main" or "Carrello", but the side menu on the left no longer opens, returns me "revealViewController() = nil" someone can help me? thank you.

[image]

Popover:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

if (indexPath.row == 0){
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainController") as! MainController
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: false, completion: nil)
 }
}
```

MainController:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MainController: UIViewController  {
 @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if revealViewController() != nil {
      menuButton.target = revealViewController()
      menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
      view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }

  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

  }

}
```

Comment: Have you checked that your Segue Identifiers in the storyboard and 100% correct (check cases) and of the correct type?

Comment: yes, because the page opens correctly and the side menu that will not open , for "MainController" is the identifier of the "View Controller" called "Main" , maybe I should use "SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController" but I can not implement it.